# Passing comma seperated string as Parameter in Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am writing a stored procedure that calls nested stored procedures, based on the value of parameters passed into it.

One of the parameters I am trying to pass into a sub procedure is a string of comma separated values. I am declaring a `varchar` in the main procedure and setting it.

My main stored procedure looks like this:

```
Declare @StatusString varchar(150)
Set @StatusString = N'''OPEN,'',''CLOSED'',''PENDING'''
```

This passes the `@Status` string variable into my nested stored procedure as a parameter.

Then, my nested stored procedure does

```
select from table where table.column in (@StatusString)
```

However, I am not getting any results. It looks like either I am not passing the parameter correctly, or I have not written the `Select` statement correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: It's best to go through the many hoops. Writing a single generic function to split a string is a one time cost. My suggestion is to go with that option AND pass out the row number as well so you would have two columns generated by the function.

Comment: Also, bypassing controls is a big no-no at almost any job. These controls are there for a reason. The only way to get around these hoops is dynamic sql via string concatenation which is something I highly advise against.

Comment: It seriously is not alot of work to make the function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909859/insert-values-into-table-after-splitting-the-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your SQL is that you can't use commas within a string to act as a delimiter in an IN clause. I.E `''OPEN,'',''CLOSED'',''PENDING''` is a single string, not 4 fields.

There are only two acceptable ways that I know of to do this.

1. Create a table valued function that accepts a string and spits back a record set. You can then feed that record set into a temp table and perform joins against the values OR you could use the recordset as your in clause (I.E. `WHERE column in (Select * from fn(@StatusString))`).
2. Create a custom data type and pass in your custom data-type to the stored procedure.

Please take notice that string concatenation was **not** listed above.

Comment: See my comment under your question

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE FUNCTION Split
    (
      @delimited nvarchar(max),
      @delimiter nvarchar(100)
    ) RETURNS @t TABLE
    (
    -- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
      id int identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
      val nvarchar(max)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
      declare @xml xml
      set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

      insert into @t(val)
      select
        r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
      from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

      RETURN
    END
    GO


    Declare @StatusString varchar(150)
    Set @StatusString = N'OPEN,CLOSED,PENDING'
--if you want them with quotes
--Set @StatusString = N'''OPEN'',''CLOSED'',''PENDING'''
    declare @t table (val nvarchar(100))
      insert into @t select * from dbo.split(@StatusString,',')
    select from table where table.column in (select val from @t)
```